# Scala appending List

Tags: list, scala, append, addition

I am starting to get into Scala for an assignment, and I've been looking for how to add an Item to a List in for about an hour now. I have found several solutions of course, and the code snipped below DOES compile, BUT the produced list is just empty. Can anyone tell me why that is?

```
  case NodeList(ls) => {
      var ls0 = List()
      ls.foreach {
        println("hey") // => printed 3 times
        i => ls0 :+ i
      }

      println(ls0) // => Empty list as output (ls contains 3 items when called)
  }
```

Would appreciate help alot! Thanks in advance.

Comment: List, as well as the majority of things in **Scala** are immutable. `ls0 :+ i` produces a new list with the value added at the end of the list and then discards the result; and at the end `ls0` continues being an empty list. - BTW, adding elements at the end of a list is extremely slow.

Comment: Thanks! So what would be the way to do this properly here? (BTW I need to append iterating over the other list, for reasons not shown in the code snipped)

Comment: Many ways actually, it depends on your end goal. You may just write a _(tail)_ recursive algorithm. You can use a `var` instead of a `val` and keep mutating the reference. You may even replace all with a `map` over the original **List**. You will be learning all those ways as you continue with your assignments, I would recommend you to take another look to your notes or use another learning material, there are plenty of books / blogs / courses / videos out there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, very much appreciated! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending an item to the list, but you never store the resulting new list. Basically, you append an item, then throw away the result, append again, throw away again, and so on.

You need to store the list somewhere.

Note that appending to a list is a bad idea: you have to iterate over the entire list to find the last element, then the next time you append, you have to do it again, and again, and again. That means your code has an algorithmic complexity of (n^2 - n)/2, when the same could be easily done in Θ(n). You should always *prepend* to a list, never append.